# How can I use TestNG for android project?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, testng

I have used TestNg for java projects and it was running fine. Now I want to use TestNG in android project for unit testing. But I faced some problems like "Couldn't connect to remote TestNG". So how can I use TestNG for Android? I am using eclipse and installed TestNG plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse IDE and then install the TestNG plugin. Same sort of problem happened to me, this solution worked for me.

Comment: I am using eclipse and I have already installed TestNG plugin. So now when use TestNG for java project it is working fine but It's giving "Couldn't connect to remoteTestNG" error while trying for android project. Have you faced same issue?